# Export All the SQL Code (NOT DATA) from Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I am wondering if anyone knows how to export code for all the Views/Saved Queries from Big Query? Is it even possible?

And if someone know how to import (even with errors), that would be much appreciated, too.

DZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Pentium10 says, you cannot export Saved Queries and there is a feature request. 
But in order to export the SQL code (NO DATA) from a view in BigQuery, it should be

> bq show --format=prettyjson project_id:dataset_name:view_name

In the json provided you can see the query which created the view in the "view" field. For example:

```
···
 "type": "VIEW",
  "view": {
    "query": "SELECT * FROM [project:dataset.view] LIMIT 10",
    "useLegacySql": true
  }
···
```

Answer (score 1):

You can export each view via BQ cli and API (so you need to script it).

> bq --query --format=prettyjson dataset.view

You cannot export Saved Queries, there is a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111961970) for it (you could +1 on that)

Comment: Hmm, so importing views is also far in future.

Comment: only if you wait otherwise script it

Comment: yea, got it. Thx